# Getting metadata of all databases available on the Internet

Tags: metadata, internet

I would like to get metadata for all (or as many as possible) databases that are available online. It does not have to be an open database. It is only the metadata that is important for me. The data I am interested in are e.g.:

- Number of tables
- Number of relations
- Number of rows in each table (or average for whole database)

Is there a place that gathers such information?

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a bit broad ... at the very least, you have to define what a 'database' is, because not all are relational & built around tables.  Even for something like mysql, what they call a 'database', Oracle would consider to be a 'schema', so would an Oracle server running 4 SIDs with 6 schemas each be 1, 4 or 24 'databases' ?

Comment: Now, if those 4 SIDs are because I have production, development, test/QA, and a daily snapshot (for backups or for long-running reports), would that change your answer?  What about if they were running on 4 different systems?  What if it was 4 virtual systems, but the same physical hardware?  Now, you might argue that you didn't ask about number of databases, but this is inversely related to the number of tables in a given database.